# random number in java, I need number every 30, I mean 30-60-90

Tags: java

I've been wondering how can I do it, I am pretty new to programming and not really good at math, maybe some of you might know how to do it

Comment: Downvoters, mention why are you downvoting ? So, that one who is new to SO can understand his mistake.

Comment: I wonder the same, maybe I am dumb for them but some people was on the same boat at some point, I've trying using the random method

Comment: If you have something you've been trying, and haven't succeeded, then you should show that in your question.

Comment: In that case, you should include in the question what you have tried and why it does not do what you expect it to do.  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: sorry guys, pretty new to this blog and stuff, I appreciate those who took some time trying to help me, I am sure with the time I'll be able to handle this in a better way

Comment: It's always worth reading the [Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) *before* asking your first question on any site (not just here).

Comment: @NicolasBuitragoAldana, please take two minutes to read these two links: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your problem is very simple and most people can help you with it, but everybody demands from those who ask to show their effort, otherwise SO would be a "do for me" website. Please insert your code in the question (even if it's wrong) and I'm sure someone will help you. Welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I guess the votes here are for lack of research.

Anyway, you use `java.util.Random`'s [`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) and multiply by 30. For instance, this gives you a random number 30 (1 * 30), 60 (2 * 3), 90 (3 * 30), and so on up to and including 3000 (100 * 30):

```
Random r = new Random();
int num = (r.nextInt(100) + 1) * 30;
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/wZ4p8A)

Remove the `+ 1` if 0 is a valid value to use (and then you won't get 3000, the highest will be 2970).

Comment: Random police = new Random();
    int police1x;   
    int police1y;
    int police2x;
    int police2y;
    
    {  police1x = police.nextInt(330);
       police1y = police.nextInt(330);
       police2x = police.nextInt(330);
       police2y = police.nextInt(330);

Comment: @NicolasBuitragoAldana: Look at your code there, and look again at the code in the answer, and note the differences.

Comment: The explain the math behind this: `nextInt` gives you a number between 0 and `N-1` (for an `N` you can choose). You can add 1 to get it between 1 and `N` and then multiply by 30 to get the first N multiples of 30.